# Find a string and replace it the whole database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a wordpress website and I'm going to change it's URL. The problem is that when I search for its actual URL in the database, I have like 200 results.

I would like to search in the whole database for the actual url and replace it with the new one.

I know that if I have the exact table and exact column, I can do :

```
UPDATE
    Table
SET
    Column = Replace(Column, 'find value', 'replacement value')
```

But how can I generalize this code to my whole database ?

Thank You !

Comment: What you're trying to do is surprisingly hard, because many entries in a WordPress MySQL database are serialized php or json, and many others aren't. There are plenty of WordPress plugins that will help you migrate a WordPress web site from one URL to another. Ask this question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not the best, one solution is to export the whole database, open the sql file in a text editor, perform the search-replace and importing again.